# CogSci has changed its name

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

As of yesterday, Cognitive Sciences has been renamed into

[Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/)

There are [various reasons](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2294/cognitive-science-reboot-2017-changing-the-name) for this. The most important reasons, imo, being that we wish to attract more experts and to show that we welcome a lot more posts than those about cognition alone.

Why am I posting it here? Because there's overlap between the sites. The name change in itself doesn't change anything about that *per se*. In terms of overlap with Biology, it's basically Neuroscience, which has been an area of overlap for years. Neuroscience questions that are **on-topic on both sites** range from

- Basic Neuroscience including Molecular Bio (membrane receptors, ion channels *etc.*) up to
- Questions on perception (vision, hearing *etc*).

I think the border between Bio is where the question enters Psychology really. For example, questions on

- Psychophysics and
- Behavior,
- Psychotherapy & mental illnesses *etc.*

...are better asked on Psych&Neurosci and may be worth migrating.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I might spend some more time over there now, though I've never been very happy with the level of question there, not that Biology itself has quite matured to that point either.